# Merging two JsonNode

Tags: java, json

I am having two JsonString which needs to be converted to a JsonNode and join these two JsonNodes. The code is working fine if the keys of both jsonnode are different, but if they are same the later will overwrite. 
These are my two JsonNodes:

> "{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}" "
>
> {\"phonetype\":\"N96\",\"cat\":\"Wy\"}".

My code produces the result as : `{"phonetype":"N96","cat":"Wy"}`

```
public class JsonJoining {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode mainNode=mapper.readTree("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");

        JsonNode resuupdateNode=mapper.readTree("{\"phonetype\":\"N96\",\"cat\":\"Wy\"}");
        JsonNode result=merge(mainNode, resuupdateNode);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    public static JsonNode merge(JsonNode mainNode, JsonNode updateNode) {

        Iterator<String> fieldNames = updateNode.fieldNames();
        while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

            String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
            System.out.println(fieldName);
            JsonNode jsonNode = mainNode.get(fieldName);

            if (jsonNode != null && jsonNode.isObject()) {
                merge(jsonNode, updateNode.get(fieldName));
            }
            else {
                if (mainNode instanceof ObjectNode) {

                    JsonNode value = updateNode.get(fieldName);
                    ((ObjectNode) mainNode).put(fieldName, value);
                }
            }

        }

        return mainNode;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to merge the two Jsonnode and produce a third jsonnode which will look like:

```
 {"firstjson":{"phonetype":"N95","cat":"WP"},
 "secondjson":{phonetype":"N96","cat":"Wy}}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a JSON array be a much better idea?

Comment: @Vlasec the return type I require is a JsonNode.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
public static JsonNode mergeCollection(JsonNode value1,JsonNode value2){
        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();

             if(value1!=null) {
                 ObjectNode node1 = mapper.createObjectNode();

                 node1.set("value1",value1);
                 node1.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> objectNode.set(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue()));
             }
             if(value2!=null) {
                 ObjectNode node2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
                 node2.set("value2",value2);
                 node2.fields().forEachRemaining(kv -> objectNode.set(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue()));
             }
        return objectNode;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode jsonArray = mapper.createArrayNode();

jsonArray.add(value1);
jsonArray.add(value2);

System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score -2):

Trust me , below code is the best way to merge two or multiple jsonnodes

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

JsonNode js1,js2,js3;

String result=js1.toString()+js2.toString()+js3.toString();
result=result.replace("}{",",");
JsonNode j=new ObjectMapper().readTree(result); // remove the duplicate entry and convert string to json
```